# Building an Excel API

Tags: excel, api, spreadsheetml

I tried unzipping the .xlsx file and could find some files in it. But I am not sure as to what these files contain and how they are related.

Where can I find the DOCS for creating spreadsheetML?

Comment: Can you clarify any further? What are you using? What .xlsx file are you talking about?  I did find [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278316.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278320.aspx) via [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=DOCS+for+creating+spreadsheetML&oq=DOCS+for+creating+spreadsheetML&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)...

Comment: what i meant was, I want to know the significance of each of the files zipped as xlsx file and how exactly the content(xml content)of these files, based on what criteria, are populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the full specification of the Open XML file formats [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm). The specification contains a description of the files that are contained in an Open XML file package (such as an XLSX file), their contents and relationships.

There are also a lot of great articles and tutorials about Office Open XML formats at the [OpenXML Developer Blog](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/default.aspx) and [Eric White's Blog](http://ericwhite.com/blog/).

For learning Office Open XML, I would recommend starting with [this](http://openxmldeveloper.org/wiki/w/wiki/introduction-to-open-xml.aspx) series of articles and [this](http://openxmldeveloper.org/wiki/w/wiki/introduction-to-spreadsheetml.aspx) to learn how SpreadsheetML (the XLSX file format) works.